# echo to file works only with sudo su

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

I am using the Jetson TK1 development board from NVIDIA which has Ubuntu 14.04 on it. It is a 4-core ARM system and by default, 3 of them are "offline" -

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu ~ $ lscpu
Architecture:          armv7l
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Off-line CPU(s) list:  1-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    3
Socket(s):             1
```

While they are supposed to automatically wake up when the scheduler detects enough load, they do not (at least for our workload). The workaround is to write a "1" into a location inside of /sys -

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
```

The documentation says to follow these commands, in order -

```
sudo su
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
```

and repeat for cpus 2 and 3. This works -

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu ~ $ sudo su
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
root@tegra-ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
root@tegra-ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# lscpu
Architecture:          armv7l
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Off-line CPU(s) list:  2,3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    3
Socket(s):             1
root@tegra-ubuntu:/home/ubuntu#
```

I don't want to use `sudo su`, personally, because it hurts my eyes but mainly because we need a script that can wake up all CPUs and then execute the command to start our workload. Ideally, I'd put it in `/etc/rc.local`. That does not work. May be the kernel powers the CPUs down after rc.local is executed at boot?

In any case, here is my script -

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo bash -c "echo '1' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online"
sudo bash -c "echo '1' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online"
sudo bash -c "echo '1' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online"
<some command>
```

The problem is, `<some command>` runs and the echo lines above do not give anything on stdout. However, `lscpu` shows only 1 CPU active. Pasting these lines into the terminal directly does not work. That was not the puzzling part for me. I assumed I messed something up. Here's what **is** puzzling. Doing `sudo su` followed by the `echo` command works, as I said earlier. Now, exiting out of root and running

```
sudo bash -c "echo '1' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online"
sudo bash -c "echo '1' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online"
```

in my user shell (user is sudoer) works. So if I do not do `sudo su`, 1 is  never echoed for any of the CPUs. But echoing after `sudo su` for one CPU lets me echo the others outside the root shell.

Finally, `tee` used like so does not work either -

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
```

Any help as to why this is happening and how I could use `sudo bash -c` from within a script in the user terminal would be appreciated.

Comment: You write a script with your command and call the script with sudo (rather then using sudo over and over in the script ).

Answer (score 1):

The reason `sudo echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online` doesn't work is because the `sudo` part applies only to the main command (`echo 1`); it doesn't apply to the redirection (`> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online`), and so the writing-to-the-file part is done under your user account.

Using something like `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online` should work, as the writing part will be done under `sudo`, while the `echo` part will be under your account. I'm not sure why it didn't work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Putting `su` at the top of the script, and then running the commands normally will work just fine. The reason you have to use `sudo su` instead of just `sudo` is because sudo only works on the main program, the redirection (`>`) is run without root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Huh.  That's weird.

This should work:

```
cat | sudo bash << "EOF"
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online
EOF
```

Perhaps the other stuff was working for you, but because you didn't disable the scaling governor it turned the cores back off before you started using them?

According to http://elinux.org/Jetson/Performance you should also `echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuquiet/tegra_cpuquiet/enable`